# Совет по оптимизации БД

Tags: база-данных, оптимизация

Здравствуйте
У меня такая дилема, я пишу скрипт интернет-магазина, и нужно чтобы была возможность добавления параметров для каждого товара. 
Я думаю сделать так:
 1. Буду привязывать поля к категориям.
 2. Товары в свою очередь будут привязаны к одной категории, и они соответственно будут иметь доступ до полей этой категории.
 3. Поля категорий будут хранится в отдельной таблице (ID записи|ID категории|Отображаемое покупателям название).

Как лучше хранить параметры товаров, в отдельной таблице или же лучше хранить в таблице товаров ( сохранение в формате JSON, в отдельной ячейке ) ?
У меня маловато опыта в оптимизации БД, если можете помогите пожалуйста.
Спасибо

Comment: А набор действий какой предполагается? По сохраненым параметрам выборка может быть?

Т.е. например, есть параметр "масса" (или "объем"). По этому параметру возможен поиск?

Если да, то как вы собираетесь вести поиск в JSON`e?

А выбирать записи как будете? JOIN'ить кучу раз одну и ту же таблицу "Параметры", чтобы получить строку, описывающую товар? Или как?

Может лучше создать несколько таблиц: первая хранит общую информацию о товаре, а остальные хранят специфичную информацию (но общую для каждого вида товара)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поля можешь хранить в одной ячейке в сериализованном виде, но тогда с поиском по полям категории будет трудновато. Если хранить в отдельной таблицу каждое поле и привязывать к категории то при запросах надо будет делать `join`-ы. Я вам советую использовать нереляционные базы данных, в частности [mongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/),  там можно хранить поля категорий в самих записях, это удобно при поиске и при редактировании дополнительных полей